# Trying to do some simple calculations in iOS project?

Tags: ios, nsstring, calculator, nsnumber

I want to know how to do some simple equations in my iOS app, if anyone could point me in the right direction that would be wonderful!

I need to know how to convert an NSNumber that represents minutes to an NSString which represents hours and minutes (example: 100 = 1 hour and 40 minutes)

I also want to know if its possible to convert something like 2013-02-08T10:50:00.000 to 10:50AM

Thanks for any tips you guys might have.

Comment: Well, for the later you could probably use NSDateFormatter.

Comment: He. Was there a comment above your previous one or something?

Comment: The person deleted their comment.

Comment: Yeah, that makes more sense. It looked like I needed to chill for my single sentence. :) I see you removed your follow up. Anyways, welcome to Stack Overflow. We hope you'll stick around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the conversion :

```
NSNumber *yourNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt100];

NSInteger hour    = [yourNumber intValue] / 60;
NSInteger minutes = [yourNumber intValue] % 60;
NSString *time_stamp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d hour and %d minutes",hour,minutes];
```

As the comments suggested you can use NSDateFormatter to format your NSDate.

Comment: How do I set an @interface selector for intValue again?

Comment: What?? sorry I did not understand your question

Comment: When I use your code, I get "No visible @interface for 'NSNumber' declares the selector 'intvalue'"

Comment: I've edited my answer, there was a typo "intvalue" -> intValue